# Javascript audio currentTime doesn't work on non-Chrome browsers

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have a problem when I use currentTime; my code below only works in google chrome. I tried other ways but with no results. Have I missed something?

```
function togglePlay(tid, tname) {
        if (myAudio.src == 'http://yoursite.com' + tname) {
            tem = myAudio.currentTime;
        } else {
            tem = 0;
        }
        myAudio.src = tname;
        rid = tid;
        if (isPlaying) {
            myAudio.currentTime = tem;
            myAudio.pause();
            isPlaying = false;
            document.getElementById(tid).className = "start";
        } else {
            myAudio.currentTime = tem;
            myAudio.play();
            isPlaying = true;
            document.getElementById(tid).className = "stop";
        }
    };
```

> I solved the problem by myself. The error was in putting out of the if myAudio.src = tname; rid = tid;

```
    function togglePlay(tid, tname) {
            if (myAudio.src == 'http://yoursite.com' + tname) {
                tem = myAudio.currentTime;
            } else {

                tem = 0;
                myAudio.src = tname;
                rid = tid;

            }
            if (isPlaying) {
                myAudio.currentTime = tem;
                myAudio.pause();
                isPlaying = false;
                document.getElementById(tid).className = "start";
            } else {
                myAudio.currentTime = tem;
                myAudio.play();
                isPlaying = true;
                document.getElementById(tid).className = "stop";
            }
        };
```

Comment: Doesn't work as in...? One thing, you are setting the currentTime right after you did set the src. At this time, there are great chances that the metadata have not been parsed yet, hence the browser doesn't know the duration and *might* ignore your setting.

Comment: Problem solved (it was on first if). Chrome is the only browser that doesn't reload src if it remains the same, so it works